# Getting value from radio button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am trying to check if the radio button is checked or not, and also I am trying to get the value but I do not know why it does not work. I saw a lot of post, video on internet and also some on this site, but nothing. So helpless I am posting this on the site.

This is my HTML file

```js
function getValue(){

    var checkAge  = false;
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
       if(document.getElementById("age"+i).checked){
      checkAge = true;
     }
    }
    

}
function loadFunctions() {
  getValue();
}

window.onload = loadFunctions;
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Tutorial</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <form id="form">
            <section id="age_question">
                <h2>How old are you?</h2>
                <label for="age-one">1-25</label>
                <input type="radio" name="ageRange" id="age1" value="0"/>
                <label for="age-two">26-40</label>
                <input type="radio" name="ageRange" id="age2" value="5" />
                <label for="age-three">41-60</label>
                <input type="radio" name="ageRange" id="age3" value="8" />
                <label for="age-four">60+</label>
                <input type="radio" name="ageRange" id="age4" value="10" />
            </section>
    
            <section id="bmi">
                <h2>What is your BMI?</h2>
                <label for="bmi-level"><span>0-25</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="bmi_range" id="" value="0"/>
                <label for="bmi-level"><span>26-30</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="bmi_range" id="" value="0" />
                <label for="bmi-level"><span>31-35</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="bmi_range" id="" value="9" />
                <label for="bmi-level"><span>35+</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="bmi_range" id="" value="10" />
            </section>
    
            <section id="family_history">
                <h2>Does anybody in your family have Diabetes?</h2>
                <label for="history"><span>No</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="f_history" id="history" value="0"/>
                <label for="history"><span>Grandparent</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="f_history" id="history" value="7" />
                <label for="history"><span>Sibling</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="f_history" id="history" value="15" />
                <label for="history"><span>Parent</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="f_history" id="history" value="15" />
            </section>
    
            <section id="diet">
                <h2>How would you describe your diet?</h2>
                <label for="diet"><span>Low sugar</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="dietHabits" id="dietHabit" value="0"/>
                <label for="diet"><span>Normal sugar</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="dietHabits" id="dietHabit" value="0" />
                <label for="diet"><span>Quite high sugar</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="dietHabits" id="dietHabit" value="7" />
                <label for="diet"><span>High sugar</span></label>
                <input type="radio" name="dietHabits" id="dietHabit" value="10" />
            </section>
            <button onclick="getValue()">Get You BMI</button>
            <p id="message"></p>
        </form>
        
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)` It should start from 1 to `<= 4` or `< 5`

Comment: I tried but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I'll suggest you do is to clear your browser cache, or launch the dev tools using F12 and check "Disable cache" on the "Network" tab.

**Edit**: Changed the button type, and made checkAge global.

Okay, the button does submit the form, making all changes to the variable lost after reload. To fix that, change the button type to just `button`, as:

```
<button type="button" onclick="getValue()">Get You BMI</button>
```

That way, it won't reload everytime you press the button. Another thing to do is make the `checkAge` variable global. that way is defined as false by default.

The `"age"+i` thing you did was starting the iteration with `i=0`, therefore giving the `elementId` as `age0`. This was making the element `null`.

To fix that, you can change the for-loop to `for(var i=1; i<=4; i++)` or using the same loop you've defined, but adding `i` by 1 before using it.

And the code would be like so:

```js
var checkAge  = false;

function getValue(){

    for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
        var index = i + 1
        var element = document.getElementById("age"+index)

        if(element.checked){
            checkAge = true;
            alert("The value is"+element.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: this gives me the value of but it does not check if the radio button is checked or not, how do i do that?

Comment: and also clearing the cache i get true but the browser does not keep the console.log

Comment: @SinghPrajit I made a few changes, check to see if they solve your problem.

Comment: now it's working thank you! How do I prevent the user to submit the form until at least one of each option is selected?

Comment: @SinghPrajit, for that case, you could the same thing you've done for age here to the other sections. Having a variable be true if the section has a checked radio button. After that you can do an AND for all the checkXXX variables to see if the form is valid. If its valid you can call "document.getElementById("form").submit();".

Comment: @SinghPrajit, if this was helpful to you, you should at least mark it as the accepted answer and upvote it to help other who might face the same.

Comment: I can't up vote but I selected as right answer. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @SinghPrajit, Much appreciated, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check the `checked` value of each of the radio buttons.

Here is a simpler solution:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var ageRange = form.ageRange.value;
```

The value will equal to an empty string (`''`) when nothing is checked. Therefore, the logic for `checkAge` could be simplified to:

```
var checkAge = ageRange !== '';
```

Comment: Hi Marko thank you for your quick answer. However I am not getting your code. Sorry for this, I am complete new in this

Comment: @SinghPrajit your answer is very vague. What exactly are you not getting? The first line finds the element with `id` of `form`, the second one finds the `ageRange` (name corresponds with the `name` of your radio buttons) value in the form and the last line sets `checkAge` to true if `ageRange` is not empty, otherwise it sets it to true. This is really basic JavaScript code with access to DOM and a simple boolean check. If you find this difficult to understand, I suggest you to start with learning the basics of JavaScript, but this is not something that should be addressed in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

your for loop is looping through i from 0 - 3, so your `document.getElementById("age"+i)` will look for id="age0", "age1", "age2, "age3".

Change your 'for' loop to `for(var i=1; i<5; i++)`

Comment: I tried this too, but it seems it does not work, it remains false.

Comment: Your `getValue()` only run once when the page loads initially.  If you run `getValue()` again after checking one of the age radio boxes, your checkAge should be set to true.

Comment: add `return checkAge` at the end of your `getValue()` function, you can see what the `checkAge` value is when you run `getValue()` in your console (after checking off one of the age radio boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Make the starting index be `1` instead of `0`, since your ID selectors start from `1`:

```
function getValue() {
  var checkAge = false

  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById('age' + i).checked) {
      checkAge = true
    }
  }

  console.log(checkAge)

  return checkAge
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a3fzd2kv/2/**

Comment: I tried and I still get false even after submitting the form

Comment: Should be true after submitting, gif http://g.recordit.co/txON3ghIvu.gif

Comment: It would help if you can specify what browser and operating system, but the code regardless should work the same

Comment: I am using google chrome and the os is Windows 10, I inserted alert box and it shows me true when I checked but once I press ok in the console I see only false